# React Native Navigation 5 Authentication Flow

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-navigation-v5

I cant seem to get the ternary authentication working on my App.js file. I'm checking to see if there is a key, then displaying either an AuthStack or a MainStack based on the presence of that key. When I go from AuthStack to MainStack (setting a key to AsyncStorage), then I get the error - The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload{'name':'Home'} was not handled by any navigator. The same happens when I Logout or remove the key.

Based on the documentation, it seemed like the user would immediately navigate into the app when authenticated, but that doesnt seem to be working.

App.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthStack from './src/navigation/AuthStack'
import MainStack from './src/navigation/MainStack'

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [userKey, setUserKey] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {

      try {
        let userKey = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userKey')
        setUserKey(userKey)

      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }

    }

    bootstrapAsync()
  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      {userKey == null ? (
        <AuthStack />
      ) : (
          <MainStack />
        )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

AuthStack

```
function AuthStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default AuthStack
```

MainStack

```
function MainStack({ navigation, route }) {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default MainStack
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal auth setup using react-navigation v5.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Auth = React.createContext(null);

export function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [pass, setPass] = React.useState('');
  
  const { setToken } = React.useContext(Auth)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(t) => setEmail(t)}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="Password"
        value={pass}
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(t) => setPass(t)}
      />

      <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => setToken('Get the token and save!')}>Submit</Button>
    </View>
  );
}

export function Home() {
const { setToken } = React.useContext(Auth)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => setToken(null)}>Signout</Button>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Auth.Provider value={{token, setToken}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {!token ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Auth.Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + 20,
    padding: 20,
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

Here is a working example.

https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/react-navigation-auth-example

Note - this is a very basic setup you must do the validation and proper token check for auth setup you cannot rely on a ternary operation that has only 2 options true or false, You might also have an intermediate state like auth checking.