# Using conditional statement in react navigation based on AWS authenticated user

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, amazon-cognito

I am using expo and AWS Cognito for my app. I am trying to divert users who are authenticated to the home screen while those who are not to the sign-in screen but cannot get the expected behavior to work. The main issue seems to be when users sign out the app does not refresh, so the AWS token is being pulled from local storage so that the user still appears to be logged in. Only when I do a hard refresh does it show they are now logged out.

Here is my App.js code to log in the user:

```
const App = () => {

  const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(
        { bypassCache: true }
      );
      console.log(userInfo.attributes.sub);

      if (!userInfo) {
        return;
      }

      if (userInfo) {
        const userData = await API.graphql(
          graphqlOperation(
            getUser, 
            { id: userInfo.attributes.sub,
            }
          )
        )


        if (userData.data.getUser) {
          console.log(userData.data.getUser);
          setUserID(userData.data.getUser)
          return;
        } else {
          setUserID(null);
        }
      }
    }
    fetchUser();

  }, [])



return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{
      userID,
      setUserID: ({}) => setUserID({}),

    }}>
      <AppNavigation/>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}}
```

And here is my code for the App Navigation where I have my conditional statement:

```
const AppNavigation = () => {

    const { userID } = useContext(AppContext);

    console.log(userID) //this gives the correct value, null when not logged in and a user object when the user is logged in.


    return (  
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator
                    drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent { ...props} />}
                    drawerPosition='left'
                    initialRouteName={userID === null ? 'SignIn' : 'HomeDrawer'}
                >
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name='HomeDrawer'
                        component={MainNavStack}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name='SignIn'
                        component={SignIn}
                    />
</Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I have tried every combination of useState and useEffect I can think of:

1. using getAuthenticatedUser on the AppNavigation screen and then setting a state if successful.
2. passing props from App.js directly
3. not using AppContext at all
4. putting it all in useEffect
5. getting the authenticated user directly from a function in the conditional statement

The problem seems to be that initialRouteName is determining the route before I can set any kind of state in the app. How can I get the expected behavior without having to hard refresh the app?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you, I also have a snack demo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118450/5519872

Comment: You need to hook up your server & act accordingly using my snack demo. My snack demo is purely based on client-side code.