# React-navigation multiple stack navigator with inital route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So i was creating RN project which had multiple stack navigator

- Logged In Routes
- Non Logged in routes

So I have non logged in routes like this

```
import React from "react"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "react-native-screens/native-stack"
import { Introduction, Login } from "@src/screens/loggedOut"

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const defaultOptions = {
  headerShown: false
}
const LoggedOutRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="introduction">
      <Stack.Screen name="introduction" component={Introduction} options={defaultOptions} />
      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} options={defaultOptions} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default LoggedOutRoutes
```

And similarly logged in routes

```
import React from "react"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "react-native-screens/native-stack"
import {Home,Settings } from "@src/screens/loggedIn"

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const defaultOptions = {
  headerShown: false
}
const LoggedIn = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
      <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} options={defaultOptions} />
      <Stack.Screen name="settings" component={Settings} options={defaultOptions} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default LoggedIn
```

Now, I want to load either of these roots based on if user is logged in or not.

How would I do it?

Comment: Check the login state and render the navigation accordingly...I don't really understand what the question is honestly.

Comment: `initialRouteName` is only used in the initial render, you need to add conditions for auth & unauth state.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795865/react-native-navigation-5-authentication-flow/68118450#68118450

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a login state saved, you can wrap your navigation in the NavigationContainer component from "@react-navigation/native" and render the correct navigation conditionally. Something like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>

  {userLoggedIn ? <LoggedIn /> : <LoggedOutRoutes />}

</NavigationContainer>
```