# react navigation are not updating after set state in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to know why my react navigation not updated after state update.
here is my code

```
const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
     _renderdata()
  }, []);

const _renderdata = async () => {
    try {
      const user_type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
      if (user_type !== null) {
        setIsShow(true)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn((error))
    }
  }
```

My view

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen> .... </Tab.Screen>
  {
    isShowUser &&
    <Tab.Screen> .... </Tab.Screen>
  }
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I want to hide one of my `tab.screen` on the basis of user type but in my case Every time the value of `isShow` is false and I am not able to view that screen . What is the issue?

full code

```
const createBottomTabs = (route) => {
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type').then(response => {
        if (response == '"Driver"') {
          setIsShow(true)
          console.log(isShow)
        }
      })
    }, 5000);
  }, [isShow]);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      lazy={true}
      labeled={false}
      shifting={true}
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffff', }}
      initialRouteName="Dashboard"
      screenOptions={{ unmountOnBlur: false }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Dashboard'
        component={Dashboard}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={Chat}
      />
      {isShow ? (
        <Tab.Screen
          name='Orders'
          component={Orders}
        />
      ) : null}
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notification"
        children={Notification}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: Add condition of the navigator, not the screen, then only the switching will work or do the check before rendering the navigator. If you can add a snack.expo.dev I can help you solve the issue

Comment: can you elaborate a little

Comment: Check this out the auth flow example https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118450/5519872

Comment: I done the same thing

Comment: Add a https://snack.expo.dev repro I will check

Comment: don't have much time if you can help me immediately tell me I will give you some of my code .

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: I would also use `if (response === '"Driver"')`. But first, is the expected value `Driver` or `"Driver"`. That would make a difference as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code

https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/dynamic-render-bottom-bar-screen

Wait for 5 seconds you will see the tab added

```
function MyTabs() {
  const [isShow, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(true);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      {isShow && <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={SettingsScreen} />}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: hello! did you find any other solution? or what is the problem? exactly the same thing is happening to me with the status and your solution helped me, but I don't think it's the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. `setiisShow` should be `setIsShow` (for correct camel case).

Comment: still not able to resolve

Comment: Are you sure `user_type` is getting set correctly? Directly below the initializer, add `console.log(user_type)`. I suspect that it is not. And what would trigger your error condition?

Comment: yes user_type set correctly I did console log to confirm that

Comment: try function running fine so error condition is not running

Comment: when I console log isShow outside the function I get true but still my  tab screen is not visible