# 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"LoginStack","params":{"screen":"Login"}} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I have an error when navigating from Home to Login Screen when the user press the button Sign out.

Here is the App component:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { LoginScreen } from "./Screens/LoginScreen";
import { HomeScreen } from "./Screens/HomeScreen";
import { SignUpScreen } from "./Screens/SignUpScreen";
import { CardScreen } from "./Screens/CardScreen";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase/firebase";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user !== null) setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  const LoginStack = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignUp"
          component={SignUpScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="CardScreen" component={CardScreen} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginStack" component={LoginStack} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is the Home component:

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { DashboardScreen } from "./DashboardScreen";
import { SettingsScreen } from "./SettingsScreen";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleSignout = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Sign out");
        navigation.navigate("LoginStack", { screen: "Login" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === "Dashboard") {
            iconName = focused ? "pin" : "pin-outline";
          } else if (route.name === "Settings") {
            iconName = focused ? "account-circle" : "account-circle-outline";
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
          );
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#95E0B6",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "gray",
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={DashboardScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button onPress={handleSignout} title="Sign out" />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export { HomeScreen };
```

I'm following the instructions described here related to the nested navigator but seems to not work: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

Any idea about how can I navigate from the Home Screen to the Login Screen?

Thanks

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118450/5519872

Answer (score 0):

Your screen stack constructor depends on user variable.
You can't navigate to a stack that is not built, but you can set the user = null and the application will render automatically to LoginStack.

The best practice to manage user signIn/signOut is to put the user state in a context.